# exsheets reorder questions

Tags: exsheets

I'm using the excellent exsheets package, and I'd like to have different orders of questions in the different variants of my test. That is, I'd like `\variant{1}` to print one order of questions, `\variant{2}` to print another, etc. So given a document like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\SetVariations{2}
\variant{1}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
foo
\end{question}

\begin{question}
bar
\end{question}

\begin{question}
baz
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

For `\variant{1}` I'd like it to render something like:

```
Exercise 1.
foo
Exercise 2.
bar
Exercise 3.
baz
```

And for `\variant{2}` I'd like it to render in some other order, say:

```
Exercise 1.
baz
Exercise 2.
bar
Exercise 3.
foo
```

I've managed to achieve something like this by defining commands like `\varyreversethree` which work like the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\SetVariations{2}
\variant{2}

\newcommand{\varyreversethree}[3]{\vary{#1#2#3}{#3#2#1}}

\begin{document}

\varyreversethree{
\begin{question}
foo
\end{question}
}{
\begin{question}
bar
\end{question}
}{
\begin{question}
baz
\end{question}
}

\end{document}
```

Some things I don't like about this solution are that I have to define a new version of it for each possible number of things that might be reversed, and I can't leave any blank lines between the arguments (e.g. between questions) or later arguments are lost.

Is there a better way to do this in exsheets?

Comment: No, there is no built-in solution in `exsheets`.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. Would it be worth filing a feature request on the [exsheets issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/issues)?

Comment: I'm not sure. I currently have no idea how I would implement a question re-ordering with a suitable user interface

Answer (score 3):

With `exsheets` successor `xsim` something like this would be possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

\DeclareExerciseCollection{exam}

\begin{document}

\collectexercises{exam}
\begin{exercise}
  foo
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}
  bar
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}
  baz
\end{exercise}
\collectexercisesstop{exam}

\printrandomexercises[sort=false,collection=exam]{3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `aux` file of the example above has

```
\XSIM {random}{a}{3,1,2}
```

Deleting the `aux` file or manually changing the order of numbers in this line will lead to another order. (That is, deleting the file may lead to the same order as the first time…). For example `\XSIM {random}{a}{1,3,2}` now gives:

[image]

If you want more control over the order in which the exercises are printed, you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim,pgffor}

\DeclareExerciseCollection{exam}

\begin{document}

\collectexercises{exam}
\begin{exercise}
  foo
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}
  bar
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}
  baz
\end{exercise}
\collectexercisesstop{exam}

\foreach \x in {3,1,2}{
  \XSIMexpandcode{\printexercise{exercise}{\x}}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to import the whole collection randomly without specifying the number of exercises? That is, something like `\printrandomexercises [sort = false, collection = exam] {all}`

Comment: @jowe_19 do you mean all exercises in the document or only all of one specific collection?

Comment: Rather all of one specific collection.

Comment: @jowe_19 I'll add a counter that will hold the number of exercises in a collection to the next release

Comment: Great news, thank you.